# Parsing a comma separated file using C using fscanf()

Tags: c, file-io, scanf

I have a file with data something like this -

```
Name, Age, Occupation
John, 14, Student
George, 14, Student
William, 23, Programmer
```

Now, I want to read the data such that each value (e.g. Name, Age etc.) are read as a string.
This is my code snippet -

```
....
if (!(ferror(input_fp) || ferror(output_fp))) {
    while(fscanf(input_fp, "%30[^ ,\n\t]%30[^ ,\n\t]%30[^ ,\n\t]", 
                name, age_array, occupation) != EOF){
        fprintf(stdout, "%-30s%-30s%-30s\n", name, age_array, occupation);
    }
    fclose(input_fp);
    fclose(output_fp);
}
....
```

However, this goes into an infinite loop giving some random output.
This is how I understand my `input conversion specifiers`.
`%30[^ ,\n\t]` -> read a string that is at the maximum 30 characters long and that 
**DOES NOT** include either a space, a comma, a newline or a tab character.
 And I am reading 3 such strings.
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `while(fscanf(stdin, " %30[^ ,\n\t], %30[^ ,\n\t], %30[^ ,\n\t]",
             name, age_array, occupation) == 3){`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OP's

```
fscanf(input_fp, "%30[^ ,\n\t]%30[^ ,\n\t]%30[^ ,\n\t]", ...
```

does not consume the `','` nor the `'\n'` in the text file.  Subsequent `fscanf()` attempts also fail and return a value of 0, which not being `EOF`, causes an infinite loop.

---

Although OP requested a `fscanf()` solution, a `fgets()/sscanf()` better handles potential IO and parsing errors.

```
FILE *input_fp;
FILE *output_fp;
char buf[100];
while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, input_fp) != NULL) {
  char name[30];  // Insure this size is 1 more than the width in scanf format.
  char age_array[30];
  char occupation[30];
  #define VFMT " %29[^ ,\n\t]"
  int n;  // Use to check for trailing junk

  if (3 == sscanf(buf, VFMT "," VFMT "," VFMT " %n", name, age_array,
      occupation, &n) && buf[n] == '\0') {
    // Suspect OP really wants this width to be 1 more
    if (fprintf(output_fp, "%-30s%-30s%-30s\n", name, age_array, occupation) < 0)
      break;
  } else
    break;  // format error
}
fclose(input_fp);
fclose(output_fp);
```

Rather than call `ferror()`, check return values of `fgets()`, `fprintf()`.

Suspect OP's undeclared field buffers were `[30]` and adjusted `scanf()` accordingly.

---

[edit]

Details about `if (3 == sscanf(buf, VFMT "," ...`

The `if (3 == sscanf(...) && buf[n] == '\0') {` becomes true when:
1) exactly the 3 `"%29[^ ,\n\t]"` format specifiers each scanf in at least 1 `char` each.
2) `buf[n]` is the end of the string.  `n` is set via the `"%n"` specifier.  The preceding `' '` in `" %n"` causes any following white-space after the last  `"%29[^ ,\n\t]"` to be consumed.  `scanf()` sees `"%n"`, which directs it to set the current offset from the beginning of scanning to be assign to the `int` pointed to by `&n`.

`"VFMT "," VFMT "," VFMT " %n"` is concatenated by the compiler to
`" %29[^ ,\n\t], %29[^ ,\n\t], %29[^ ,\n\t] %n"`.
I find the former easier to maintain than the latter.

The first space in `" %29[^ ,\n\t]"` directs `sscanf()` to scan over (consume and not save) 0 or more white-spaces (`' '`, `'\t'`, `'\n'`, etc.).  The rest directs `sscanf()` to consume and save *any* 1 to 29 `char` *except*  `','`, `'\n'`, `'\t'`, then append a `'\0'`.

Comment: Can you explain this statement -                                   `(3 == sscanf(buf, VFMT "," VFMT "," VFMT " %n", name, age_array,
      occupation, &n) && buf[n] == '\0')`.                      Also, why is there a **space** inside `" %29[^ ,\n\t]"`. I am not able to get the last column too.

Comment: @Vishal Yadav See edit.  That space consumes the spaces between `","` and `"Age"`.  The "the last column" problem was likely a missing `s` in `"%-30s%-30s%-30\n"`, which is now corrected.

Answer (score 3):

You're not skipping the actual commas and spaces between the values.

Once the first `%30[^ ,\n\t]` specifier has matched, the input probably contains a comma and a space, which aren't matched by the following thing in the format string.

Add comma and space to the formatting string where expected in the input:

```
while(fscanf(input_fp, "%30[^ ,\n\t], %30[^ ,\n\t], %30[^ ,\n\t]", name, age_array, occupation) == 3)
                                    ^             ^
                                    |             |
                                    \             /
                                   add these to make
                                   fscanf() skip them
                                      in the input!
```

Also, your check of `fscanf()`'s return value is sub-optimal: before relying on the values to have been converted, you should check that the return value equals the number of conversions.

Plus, your use of the backslash line-continuation character is completely pointless and should be removed.

Comment: Can you explain how exactly?

Comment: I get the part that the first string may contains a ',', but how do I skip the 'non-essential character'? Could you explain the fscanf()'s return value part. In many examples that I have gone through, this is how the ending of file has been checked. (by 'non essential character' I mean any whitespace or comma)

Comment: Fail at the input of the second line after the input of the first line has been completed.

Comment: Needs to consume the final `'\n'` somewhere.  Maybe space before first 30 `" %30[^ ,\n\t]...` or `...\n\t]%*c"` at the end.