# how to parse three comma separated strings from terminal using fgets()/sscanf()

Tags: c, scanf

After reading [Parsing a comma separated file using C using fscanf()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21410500/parsing-a-comma-separated-file-using-c-using-fscanf) I made some progress but I'm still having difficulty parsing this.

Input from the console is expected to be up to three strings, separated by commas  e.g. "String1,String2,String3" or "String1,String2" or "String1"

I can handle input validation after I get this working. I need to parse this input into three separate char* strings.

So far I have

```
char arg1[9] = "UNDEF";
char arg2[17] = "UNDEF";
char arg3[33] = "UNDEF";
char inputBuffer[100];

char* end = "END";

while(strcmp(arg1, end) != 0)
{
  printf("ENTER INSTRUCTION:");
  fgets(inputBuffer, sizeof(inputBuffer), stdin);
  sscanf(inputBuffer, "%[^,\n]s,%[^,\n]s,%s" arg1,arg2,arg3);
  printf("arg1: %s\narg2: %s\narg3: %s\n", arg1,arg2,arg3);
}
```

But when I run this with input `"test,test,test"` from the terminal, it outputs

```
arg1: test
arg2: UNDEF
arg3: UNDEF
```

It's obvious I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what ... this is new territory for me; I've never written in C and I haven't written C++ since my two semesters of c++ classes three years ago.

Comment: Did the code tag eat a quotation mark? `sscanf(inputBuffer, "%[^,\n]s,%[^,\n]s,%s, arg1,arg2,arg3);`

Comment: Do you _have_ to have `fscanf()`? `fgets()` and `strtok()` can do the job in more elegant and flexible way. [It should read `sscanf()`]

Comment: Er ... I need to change the title, I'm using fgets()/sscanf() ... how would strtok() behave differently than sscanf()?

Comment: `strtok()` behaviour won't be different, rather, it'll give you the expected o/p in a rather structured way. I personally don't like to use `scanf()` family, `fgets()` and `strtok()` is a better combination for me. Do you like to have an alternate approach? otherwise my reply would not have any sense in this context.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I don't get why strtok() is being suggested because it modifies the input string and also OP's code is good fgets() followed by sscanf() is a good idea and just scanning has gone wrong which should be taken care ..

Comment: @Gopi as I said, it's my opinion. I never said OP's approach is wrong. Sometimes, an alternate approach helps. and really do you think `because it modifies the input string`, `strtok()` should not be suggested?

Comment: @SouravGhosh No I meant with suggesting `strtok()` it gives an impression OP is doing something wrong which is not true. Anytime alternatives are good

Comment: I'll take a look at strtok() just to see, but as others have said, this is (mostly) good, so I'll just fix it :) Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get rid of `s`

```
sscanf(inputBuffer, "%[^,\n],%[^,\n],%s", arg1,arg2,arg3);
```

`[^,\n]` will scan till `,` is enountered and store the scanned value in your `char array`.

PS: `fgets()` comes with a newline char.

Comment: I thought fgets() ate the newline, but when I compared to END it wasn't working unless followed by a comma, but when I added the \n to the expression it worked ... I figured the sscanf() was taking in the newline and appending it so it was END\n ... Actually, looking at the console output when I remove the \n, that's exactly what happened.

So I guess what my original was saying was <anything not a comma><a string ending in comma><anything not a comma><a string ending in comma><a string> ?

Comment: @DanielBall You need to supress the newline char by doing `if(a[strlen(a)-1] == '\n') a[strlen(a) -1] = '\0' `  Then you don't have `\n` in your buffer. Latter you should be saying read till comma is enountered and the right way to say is as shown above. One more thing is always check the return value of sscanf() which will be very helpful